# What is the equivalent of a div or table with fixed height in openxml/worprocessingml

Tags: html, openxml, tabular, wordprocessingml

I want to include a table inside a div element so that whatever the number of rows of my table, my document is always structured the same way.

How can I do that?

The second solution would be to define a fixed height directly  to the table but i can't find how.

Answer (score 0):

To set the height of the table you need to set the height of each table row, otherwise, it will autofit to contents.

Heres the C# sample code:

```
Table newTable = new Table(
                           new TableRow(
                                new TableRowProperties(
                                     new TableRowHeight() { Val = (UInt32Value) x}), 
                                new TableCell()));
```

x corresponts to the height in dxa points. One inch corresponds to about 1440 dxa points on my 1080p monitor at 72DPI.

Article on OpenXML sizing: http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set the row height. Below I set the first row to at least 0.25" and the second to exactly 0.25"

```
<w:tr w:rsidR="00F11384" w:rsidTr="00F11384">
    <w:trPr>
        <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="360"/>
    </w:trPr>

...

<w:tr w:rsidR="00F11384" w:rsidTr="00F11384">
    <w:trPr>
        <w:trHeight w:val="360"/>
    </w:trPr>
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not a reliable solution for my problem. Maybe include a table inside a table row should have been a solution. Eventually ,  I have fixed my problem differently.